# Improving type-ahead suggestions in Search using SOLR

Tags: search, solr, lucene, search-engine

What are the possible ways you could improve the type-ahead (auto-complete) suggestions that appear in a free-form search?

From my understanding, all the suggestions that appear for keywords are stored in a SOLR table.

How do you ensure that it covers all the industry specific relevant type-ahead suggestions?

Can you automate including most recent user generated queries that are not currently providing search results to lead to relevant ones?

Answer (score 0):

In preprocessing, the documents fed into the search engine need to be enriched with whatever is sensible and provides help to find them. E.g. a document containing the string `paris` may be enriched by `french capital`, `capital of france`, `ile-de-france`, … You will need a dictionary to do so. You can take data from dbpedia.org or—for English only—WordNet. For not to over-generalize you will need to implement some disambiguation (meaning discovery) in the first step, since `paris`—for example—could equally be expanded with `alexandros`, `alaksandu of wilusa`, `king of troy`, depending on the context.